# How can I find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point(−3,f(−3))?

Tags: calculus

**Let f(t)=2/(t+8)**

(a) Simplify the following difference quotient as much as possible: 
[f(t+h)−f(t)]/h

**MY ANSWER (CORRECT)**: −2/[(t+8)(t+h+8)]

(b) Use your result from (a) and the limit definition of the derivative to calculate 
f'(t)=lim_h→zero [f(t+h)−f(t)]/h=

**MY ANSWER (CORRECT)**: −2/[(t+8)^2]

(c) Use your answer from part (b) to evaluate 
f'(−3)

**MY ANSWER (CORRECT)**: −2/25

(d) Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point 
(−3,f(−3))

y= ?

I have tried the point-slope formula, y−y_1=m(x−x_1), but my answer was incorrect.

Comment: note that $m=-2/25, x_1=-3,y_1=2/5$, plug these into your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your equation has the form
$$y=-\frac{2}{25}x+n$$ you you can plug $$x=-3,y=\frac{2}{5}$$ in the equation above and you will get $n$
I have got
$$y=-\frac{2}{25}x+\frac{4}{25}$$